# Difference between Google app engine and google cloud storage

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

We are building an architecture that will transfer 1 GB of data everyday at a specific time to 300 android devices. Initially the data will be transferred from a standalone PC to a remote data storage. We are considering services from Google. Which google services might be used for this scenario (Google App Engine or Google Cloud Storage)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would read the documentation about each of these products, then you can make an informed decision. This is especially important when making architectural decisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Rene, you can use GCS to store data. Your application logic can be served out of GAE.

What language are you using to develop your application? My recommendation would be to use Java or Python 2.7 for now.

For authentication, you can use the oAuth services: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/

To interact with GCS, use the recommended GAE SDK:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/

Answer (score 2):

Use Cloud Storage to store the file, if you set the appropiate cache headers you can save in traffic.  Use App Engine to authenticate users and then to give them the cloud storage url to download the file.  You can omit the GAE part and from inside the mobile app construct the url with the path to download the file everyday.
Storing files in GCS is much cheaper than storing them in GAE.